# BULK INSERT from multiple files using Python

Tags: python, sql, database, csv

I want to upload more than 11k .csv files on my SQL Server in the same table. The problem is the very first file being uploaded, while other files are ignored. There are no error messages at all, and paths are being read correctly. Here's the code:

```
import os
import pyodbc
import time

server = r"Server Adress"
db = r"Test Bulk"

conn_str = f"""
DRIVER={{SQL Server}};
SERVER={server};
DATABASE={db};
Trusted_Connection=yes
"""

# Path to the directory containing CSV files
csv_directory = r"C:\DataPath"

# Opening a connection to the database
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# fix the start time
start_time = time.time()

# Create a new table in the database
table_name = "CryptoData"
create_table_query = f"""
CREATE TABLE {table_name} (
    [Name] VARCHAR(30),
    [Symbol] VARCHAR(30),
    [Date] DATE,
    [Open] FLOAT,
    [High] FLOAT,
    [Low] FLOAT,
    [Close] FLOAT,
    [Adj Close] FLOAT,
    [Volume] INT
)
"""
cursor.execute(create_table_query)
cnxn.commit()

# Go through all the CSV files in the directory
for csv_file in os.listdir(csv_directory):
    if csv_file.endswith(".csv"):
        csv_file_path = os.path.join(csv_directory, csv_file)

        # Create a Bulk Insert SQL query
        bulk_insert_query = f"""
        BULK INSERT {table_name}
        FROM '{csv_file_path}'
        WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n', FIRSTROW = 2)
        """

        # Bulk Insert
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(bulk_insert_query)
        cnxn.commit()

# Measuring the time after the import is completed
end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"Import completed in {elapsed_time} seconds")
# Import completed in 31.867586851119995 seconds

# Close connection with db
cnxn.close()
```

Another thing, when I tried to run this code twice (without creating a CryptoData table for the second time ofc), the first file was successfully uploaded twice.